# How to select a specific row and column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the value from the column "classification" of the second row.

I have :
id = 'D1-0021';
LeftRight = 'R'

So with this information i want the result to the corresponding column of classification.

Can some explain with pandas how to make something like :

```
table.loc['D1-0021', where 'LeftRight' == R] get value['classification']
```

corresponding output : 'Benign'

```
       LeftRight  Age  number    abnormality classification subtype
id                                                                  
D1-0021         L   22       2  calcification         Benign     NaN
D1-0021         R   22       2  calcification         Benign     NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the data:

```
df.query('id=="D1-0021" & LeftRight=="R"')['classification']
```

Output:

```
id
D1-0021    Benign
Name: classification, dtype: object
```

And to get the string specifically, use `.item()`:

```
df.query('id=="D1-0021" & LeftRight=="R"')['classification'].item()
```

Or:

```
# query to filter data
# loc to access the value:
df.query('LeftRight=="R"').loc['D1-0021','classification']
```

**Update**: when `R` coming from a variable:

```
var = 'R'

df.query('LeftRight==@var').loc['D1-0021','classification']
```

Comment: If the "R" come from a variable as exemple : leftOrRight = "R". How do you replace the "R" with the variable name ?

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know where i can reed about this ? I dont know what to type on google for that ^^'

Comment: @AubreyDekker the official documents on [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and on [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-query) are good start.

Answer (score 1):

To select rows whose column value equals a scalar, some_value, use ==:

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value]
```

in your example below should be like:

```
table.loc[D1-0021['classification '] == Benign]
```

Comment: In my case I want to know the 'classification' value only knowing the 'id' and the 'LeftRight'

Comment: Ah ok, you could use the id column then. I'm glad you made it then.